# Using BCC field in Outlook 2010 Emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, bcc

In Outlook 2010, is there a way to have the BCC field always available for all emails?

This may have been asked in the past and if so, kindly point me to the correct response(s)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a new e-mail message and click on the **Options** tab:

   [image: 1]
2. In the **Show Fields** area click the **Bcc** button:

   [image: 2]
3. Henceforth you should see the field always when composing mails

<sub>[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299804)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Summing up the article, a new email allows you to go to the Options tab, and then select Bcc. This will be maintained on any new email messages.

Please let me know if there are any additional questions or comments.

Article:[BCC in Outlook](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2012/03/23/5-tips-on-using-bcc-in-outlook-.aspx)

[image: BCC in Outlook 2010]